# Can't type in textfield with placeholder and ng-model (only in safari)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, safari

When I type text in the first field the text shows up. After going to the next field with tab or mouse the field stays blank. This applies for all field besides the first one.

I have the following HTML:

```
<form name="HomeAccountForm" ng-submit="HomeAccountForm.$valid && fModel.accept && submit()" novalidate>


  <input name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Voornaam*" ng-model="fModel.firstname" required>
  <input name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Achternaam*" ng-model="fModel.lastname" required>
  <input name="profilename" type="text" placeholder="Profielnaam*" ng-model="fModel.profilename" required>
  <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email*" ng-model="fModel.email" required>

  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord*" ng-model="fModel.password" required>
  <input name="passwordCheck" type="password" compare-to="fModel.password" placeholder="Wachtwoord herhaling*" ng-model="fModel.passwordCheck" required>


  <input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" ng-model="fModel.accept" />
      <label for="accept">Ik ben 18 jaar of ouder en ga akkoord met de <a href="/#/">Algemene Voorwaarden.</a>*</label>

  <input type="submit" class="button" ng-disabled="!HomeAccountForm.$valid || !fModel.accept" value="Bevestigen">

</form>
```

If I remove the placeholders everything works fine. The same apply when I remove all ng-models.

But this only happens in safari (desktop / IOS).

I have also tested Firefox, IE8, IE9, IE10, Chrome and safari technology preview but here everything works fine.

[image: In the image I am typing in all fields. Only in the first res]

In the image I am typing in all fields. Only in the first result in text

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp the latest version of safari are not supported.

Comment: Never had any problems with safari and placeholders. I guess its the combination.